# Java Quick Array Error

Tags: java

I'm having a little trouble with a simple code.  It is suppose to be a program where people can add Notes that get stored in an array.  I know this code is long but hopefully some can help me out.

```
public class NoteOrganizer {

    int action = 0;
    public static Note[] myArray;

    public static void addNotes(int num)
    {
        String note;
        String date;

        for(int z = 0; z <= num; z++)
        {
            Scanner getLi = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter a note (max 140 characters): \n");
            note = getLi.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please enter a date:\n");
            date = getLi.nextLine();

            Note test = new Note();
            test.id = z;
            test.myNote = note;
            test.date = date;
            myArray[z] = test;  // THE ERROR IS IN THIS LINE, NOT THE LINE MENTIONED BEFORE

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        int action = 0;

        int y = 0;

        Scanner getLi = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please press 1 to add notes, 2 to delete notes or 3 to view "
                + "all notes:\n");
        action = getLi.nextInt();

        if(action == 1)
        {

            System.out.println("How many notes would you like to add: \n");
            int d = getLi.nextInt();
            //myArray = new Note[d];
            addNotes(d);
            //System.out.println(myArray[0].print());

        }
        else if(action == 3)
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
        }

    }
}
```

The error that I am getting is the

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at note.organizer.NoteOrganizer.addNotes(NoteOrganizer.java:46)
    at note.organizer.NoteOrganizer.main(NoteOrganizer.java:95)
Java Result: 1
```

I commented which line the error was in.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

You haven't initalized your Note array. It seems you've commented out that line for some reason:

```
//myArray = new Note[d];
```

Comment: ... and that's why I hate `public static Everything`. It can change from anywhere.

Comment: @user1834218 Java does not automatically resize an array. Look into `ArrayList`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static Note[] myArray;

 myArray[z] = test;
```

You did not initialize the array, so it is still null.

Once you know the length you need (seems to be `num`), you can do

```
myArray = new Note[num];
```

before using the array.

(It seems you already had code to that effect, but it is commented out for some reason).

Answer (score 1):

You've never set `myArray` to anything, so you can't write into it.

You're trying to automatically expand an array by writing to it, but that doesn't work in Java. However, an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) does support writing at the end (but not any further), and reallocates its internal array as neccessary:

```
ArrayList<Note> myList = new ArrayList<Note>();
```

Then, instead of

```
myArray[z] = test;
```

use

```
myList.add(test);
```

(which will automatically append to the end of the `List`, wherever it is)

then read from the list as

```
myList.get(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need initialize your array, I suggest use the class ArrayList, that is like a dynamic array.

```
myArray = new Note[length];
```